# Windows 8 won't boot from grub

Tags: grub2

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I got Ubuntu working just fine, but when I restart into grub and try to load windows 8 nothing happens,I don't know what to do.

This is a link to my bootinfo summary
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6435004/

Comment: change UEFI mode to legacy mode in bios.And then ran boot-repair.

Comment: there isn't an option to change UEFI mode to legacy mode in my bios

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Use have two efi partitions. UEFI really only works with one. But you seem to have some efi boot files in the second one? Is that a backup?

Either way you need to remove boot flag from sda6. Use gparted from live installer to change flags.

Also backup entire efi partition so you have current files.

Boot-Repair has run its rename function, so booting Windows actually is booting grub and from grub you boot this entry.

"Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi"

If you can boot the Ubuntu entry directly from UEFI. Then you do not need the rename function.

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

But if your UEFI only boots Windows you have to have the rename.